# The out parameter must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

Tags: c#

```
private void getDetails(out IPAddress ipAddress, out int port)
{
    IPAddress Ip;
    int Port;

    try
    {
        Ip = IPAddress.Parse(textboxIp.Text);
        Port = int.Parse(textboxPort.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        IPAddress Ip null;
        int Port = -1;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Why i got this compiler error ?
my parameters assigned to value in both cases

Comment: If you want to use out parameter you must assign value inside your method. Else you can use ref parameters.

Comment: `IPAddress Ip null;` is invalid and not what you have in your real code (or you'd get a different error -- one that would not lead to this question). Please post your real code.

Comment: You're assigning to local variable not parameter

Comment: Actually your code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're not assigning any values to the parameters passed into the method - `ipAddress` and `port`.  Instead of declaring new `Ip` and `Port` variables, just assign the values to the parameters you've passed in:

```
private void getDetails(out IPAddress ipAddress, out int port)
{
    try
    {
        ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(textboxIp.Text);
        port = int.Parse(textboxPort.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ipAddress = null;
        port = -1;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** For other developers, if using "out", you must allow the variable the ability to be set at all points in the function - including "if" statements, and the "catch", like here, just like it was being returned, or it will give the error this guy got.

Answer (score 7):

No, you have created another variable - `int Port`, that is not the same as `out int port`.  You are not assigning a value to the actual out parameter.  Same goes for the `ipAddress` out parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning values to both of the `out` variables. You are justassigning values to the ones you created inside the method.

Answer (score 2):

Quite obviously, you don't assign any value to your `out` parameters `ipAddress` and `port` at any point in the method.